# Single VNet and subnet PER VM in scale set?

Tags: azure, networking, azure-vm-scale-set

I cannot seem to find documentation or a way to figure this out and primarily want to use ARM templates to do this:

I am experiencing HTTP timeouts in a scale set and we have many (hundreds) of VM's in the scale set.
They are using 1 VNet and subnet for the overall scale set but how can I get it to provision 1Vnet and subnet PER virtual machine in the scale set?

Is there some trick or undocumented change that needs to be made to have the scale set do this?

Our VM's make lots of HTTP calls and believe it is being ether throttled or too congested so I want to try and be able to make the network config separate and specific for each VM.

Without using VMSS, we never had the issue until we migrated to VMSS. This is the 1 thing that appears to be different in terms of the configuration settings.

Comment: Why don't you want to get it to provision 1Vnet and subnet PER virtual machine in the scale set? Are there enough IP addresses for your vmss instances when they are deployed in a subnet?

Comment: Yes plenty IPs.

Comment: What's your specific error? If you scale the instance count to 1, does this issue still exist? Is there any network connection issue?

Comment: We get http timeouts in our tests and host process crashes randomly. If we just do it on a regular VM, no issues

Comment: I know it works on a regular VM but what about on VMSS with 1 count instance?

Comment: Same issue it seems but will continue to try a few times to get better data

Comment: Any update or process?

Comment: Still working on it unfortunately.